# Jquery Mobile mobile.changePage, new page binding to "init" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to use `mobile.changePage` to open a new page which contains a form, on this new page I'm binding to the `init` event like I've read in many other questions. The problem is that the script in my new page is not executed until i manually refresh the page.

Here is my code, I've removed useless parts because it still won't work even in the following simple version:

the maptest.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Mappa</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />


<style type="text/css">
    .ui-icon-opzione {
        background-image: url("img/opzione.gif") !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"     src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="js/maptest.js">    </script>


<!-- /DIV DELLA PAGINA  -->
<div id="home-page" data-role="page" style="width:100%; height:100%;">


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
            <ul>

                <li><a data-role="button" id="apriLista" data-icon="grid">Lista</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="mainmenu.html" rel="external" data-icon="home">Main Menu</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <select id="opzioni-mappa"  data-icon="opzione" class="ui-btn-right" data-corners="false"
        data-iconpos="notext">
            <option data-placeholder="true" value="Options"><b>OPZIONI</b>
            </option>
            <option value="segnalaServizio">Inserisci Nuovo servizio</option>
            <option value="annuncioSitter">Nuovo annuncio Dog Sitter</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

the maptest.js script:

```
// I know I shouldn't be using this, but that's not the point.
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#opzioni-mappa").change(function () {

    if ($("#opzioni-mappa").val() == "segnalaServizio") {

        alert("segnalaservizio");
        $.mobile.changePage("formtest.html");
    }

});
});
```

the formtest.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

</head>

<style>
.ui-icon-opzione {
    background-image: url("img/opzione.gif") !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style>

<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/formtest.js"></script>


<div data-role="page" id="inserisciServizio">


    <div data-role="content">

        <h3>Inserisci nuovo servizio</h3>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- content -->


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

the formtest.js script:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
alert("page opened");

});
```

the alert won't show.

Comment: can you post your pages here?

Comment: Put formtest.js inside `page` div. when using changePage, Ajax loads `body` tag contents only and neglects head.

Comment: @Omar I ran into a same problem. I am using the function mentioned on this page http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/29/reload-the-same-page-without-blinking-on-jquery-mobile/. When I do some action etc it changes the URL in address bar but doesn't change the page. It just take the person to the first page of the app. Any idea why ?? any help will be great thnx

Comment: @colourtheweb hi, could you pls post a question with all relevant data? The code in the link given is used when you want to refresh the page. That's why it goes to first page.

Comment: Yes basically what i have done is this:

function refreshPage(URL) {
   alert(URL);
    $.mobile.changePage(
   URL,
   {
     allowSamePageTransition : true,
     transition              : 'none',
     showLoadMsg             : false,
     reloadPage              : true
   }
    );
  }

So If you see I have made the page redirect and refresh page dynamic

Instead of window.location.href I have done URL which contains the ID of the page

Comment: @colourtheweb please post a question, it's free ;)